# Inserting text from textarea to mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form with a textarea field. When i add some html code. It's inserting into the table properly but with extra slashes. Before inserting the code i used the mysql_real_escape_string function and stipslashes function. But still no use. The data adding with the slashes. What's the problem ? Is i have to use any other functions??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `stripslashes()` when you are reading from the database.

Maybe you have magic_quotes_gpc on, please paste some code.

Comment: sorry i'm not used stripslahes ... After used this function it's working properly..

Comment: Accept as correct answer if it is (tick checkmark on the left). Cheers.

Comment: After i used this.. Still i'm getting some extra tags and letters like rn rn rn.. How i can avoid this??

Comment: That was `\r\n` (return carriage - newline), convert them to br for usage in HTML with `str_replace("\r\n", "<br />", $string);` then apply `stripslashes($string);`